# mysql_real_escape_string and special characters

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm working on OpenCart to make an application for importing data from an ERP.
In some descriptions of the items is sometimes used the character "°" (degree).
The application of insert of the standard software in question used "mysql_real_escape_string" and accepts the character specified above.
In my application I use the same function, but the function imports  only the previous characters before of "°" and then moves on to the next product. 
I've tried to debug and the variable contains the rightdescription.
Certenly there's an error, but I don't understand where is.
Has anyone had a similar problem and solved it?
How?

thanks
bye

This is my code

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET name = '" .  $this->db->escape($description_it) . "' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id  . "' AND language_id = '2'");
```

and this is the function of Opencart

```
public function escape($value) {
    if ($this->link) {
        return mysql_real_escape_string($value, $this->link);
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of open cart are you using?

Comment: you should try to `echo` the sql string...then execute it using a mysql tool like command line or mysql workbench

Comment: Thank you Logan Murphy. I solved this problem with the function utf_encode()   "$this->db->escape(utf8_encode($description_it))"  , because my the text files are in ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

reverse params:

string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )

you need change your rows:

```
 mysql_real_escape_string($this->link, $value);
```